# Oracle Insert with nodeJS causing missing keyword error

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am trying to create table and insert data into oracle db using nodeJS

below is my query code

```
oracledb.getConnection(
    {
        user: userId,
        password: password,
        connectString: `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ${host})(PORT = ${port}))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ${sid})))`
    },
    function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            errorHandler(err);
            return;
        }
        connection.execute(
            query,
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    errorHandler(err);
                    oracleFunctions.connection.doRelease(connection, errorHandler);
                    return;
                }

                successHandler(result);
                oracleFunctions.connection.doRelease(connection, errorHandler);
            });
    });
```

As a query I am using the below for creating table.

```
begin
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE "table0" ("Channel" VARCHAR(128),
"Pay_mode" VARCHAR(128),
"Product_group" VARCHAR(128),
"PivotDimension" VARCHAR(128),
"Values" DECIMAL(18,6))';
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE "table1" ("Channel" VARCHAR(128),
"Pay_mode" VARCHAR(128),
"Product_group" VARCHAR(128),
"PivotDimension" VARCHAR(128),
"Values" DECIMAL(18,6))';
end;
```

I am also using the below for inserting data into the created tables.

```
INSERT ALL
INTO "table0" VALUES ('AM' , 'PP' , 'NP ISP Annuity' , '1' , '0.11' )
INTO "table0" VALUES ('AM' , 'PP' , 'NP ISP Annuity' , '2' , '0.26' )
SELECT * from dual;
```

These queries work perfectly on Jetbrain's DataGrip.

I am executing the create table query first and when success response is returned, I am inserting rows into the tables.

However, strangely, when I execute the code, two errors occur

```
Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

for creating table and

```
Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

for inserting into the table.

Even more strangely, the table gets created fine but the insertion does not happen.

I have checked many times to make sure that the create table runs only once and insertion only runs once for each table. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Run `DROP TABLE "table1"` before you execute your plsql begin block

Comment: It would help if you could create a reproducible test case. Your query code is just a piece of the overall code that's giving you the errors. Please show us something we can run on our side to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange here. You're asked to do doubtful things and Oracle tries to complete it, no more.

First of all, when using Oracle, you should almost never to create tables dinamically. `ORA-955` means that you executed your request more than once. You created tables, ok. You asked to create it again. What answer you're waiting for? Oracle said that these tables already exists. Nothing strange, I guess.

`ORA-905`, most probably, means that you tries to execute `select * from dual` as a part of `INSERT ALL` statement. Oracle is waiting for next `INTO` statement but got `SELECT` instead of it, so it indicates syntax error. Again, nothing strange.

Comment: I did mention that the query runs only once so there can't be same table while the entire query is being executed - Of course I delete them before I do another round of test. As to INSERT ALL and Select * from dual, INSERT ALL expects SELECT statement at the end... SELECT * from dual; just to return dummy text..

Comment: Yes, sorry for my haste about INSERT ALL. Then, if you delete the tables... you can use something like `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'table0'` to check which object forces ORA-955